# Conditional Probability against Combinatorics

Tags: probability

Consider a lot consisting of 3 blue balls and 1 red ball.

Suppose I pick 2 balls one after another without replacement, now the probability of 2 balls being blue:

$$\frac{3\choose 2}{4 \choose 2}$$

Now taking different approach using conditional probability, the solution is also:

$$\frac34\times\frac23$$

Now it turns out that both of them evaluate to $1/2$.

Why this happens and does it happen always?

Is solving the problem using combinations an efficient approach always?

Or am I missing something basic out here!

Comment: Without replacement is the keyword here. The combinations approach results in an arrangement without replacement. Hence the answer matches.  Try to solve the same problem with replacement=True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are talking of drawing without replacement.

For the particular case you have given, the two approaches match, **but beware**

If the question were probability of getting 1 red, 1 blue

$(a) \dfrac{{3\choose1}{1\choose1}}{4\choose2} = \dfrac12$ , but

$(b) \dfrac34\cdot\dfrac13 = \dfrac14$ and you need to multiply by $2!$ to take into account different orders in which the events can occur.

On the other hand, if the problem asked the probability of a red followed by a blue,

$(b) \dfrac34\cdot\dfrac13 = \dfrac14$ is correct,

and for $(a)$, you need to **divide** $\dfrac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{4}{2}}= \dfrac12$ by $2!$ to get the specified order

Adopting the KISS approach, I use combinations when order is unspecified, and direct multiplication of probabilities when order is specified.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are correct. Both methods can be viewed as
combinatorial.

In your first approach, your sample space consists of ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ unordered samples, each with probability $1/6.$ 
Three of the six outcomes correspond to choosing two blue balls,
for a probability of $1/2.$ It is OK to use
unordered samples because we are interested in the number of balls
chosen of each color, not the order in which choices were made.

> Maybe the balls are numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, with the first three being
>   blue. Then outcomes that satisfy your event are $\{12, 13, 23\}$.
>   (I use $numerical$ order in this listing because the $actual$ order
>   of listing is irrelevant.

In your second approach, you can consider that you have a
sample space consisting of $12$ ordered outcomes, each with
probability $1/12.$ Six of the twelve ordered outcomes have two
blue balls, so the probability is $1/2.$

This second approach would be necessary if you wanted to answer
a question such as "What is the probability I choose a blue
ball first and then the red one?"

> Numbering the balls as before, the six outcomes out of twelve that satisfy
>   the event $\{\text{Two Blue}\}$ are $\{12, 13, 23, 21, 31, 32\}.$
>   Here I am not free to use numerical order in making my list because
>   the actual order of selection does matter.

Answer (score 1):

*This is one more method to solve this problem:*
Consider a Lot consists of {B1,B2,B3,R} B:Blue ball R:Red ball.

**Now list out all the combinations we get when we choose 2 balls from the Lot, one after another(without replacement).Let the event be S.**

S={(B1,B2),(B1,B3),(B1,R),(B2,B1),(B2,B3),(B2,R),(B3,B2),(B3,B1),(B3,R),(R,B1),(R,B2),(R,B3)}.

**Now our event E is getting 2 Blue balls,**

E={(B1,B2),(B1,B3),(B2,B1),(B2,B3),(B3,B2),(B3,B1)}.

Now probability of getting event E is,
**P(E)=n(S)/n(E);which is 6/12=1/2.** n:cardinality of a set(ie.number of elements).

**Inference:**
There is hell a lot of way to get solution to a probability question,all the answers match provided the approach is right.Everyone chooses their own approach,so there is no "efficient" approach. This is also a reason why I(Most of us) love it.